# How to list all non ascii bytes with awk?

Tags: bash, awk

Here is the test file on google drive.

[sample :test file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9BpilWzmmMCSGtvSm56YVhSQ2c)

I want to list all bytes non ascii byte which beyond \x00-\x7f with awk in the test file.
There are 12 bytes beyond \x00-\x7f.

It is my try.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=""}{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)if($i~/[^\x00-\x7f]/)print i,$i}'  test
146 “
148 ”
181 “
184 ”

awk 'BEGIN{FS=""}{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)if($i~/[^\x00-\x7f]/)printf("%d %x \n", i,$i)}'  test
146 0 
148 0 
181 0 
184 0
```

Failed,how to list all the 12 bytes in the file as below format.

```
146  e2
147  80
148  9c
150  e2
151  80
152  9d
185  e2
186  80
187  9c
190  e2
191  80
192  9d
```

[image: test file in hex format with xxd test command]

```
export LC_ALL=C
awk 'BEGIN{FS=""}{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)if($i~/[^\x00-\x7f]/)printf("%d %c\n",i,$i)}'  test
146 
147 �
148 �
150 
151 �
152 �
185 
186 �
187 �
190 
191 �
192 �
```

How to fix my code?

Comment: I'd say that you forgot those 2 `e2` before the groups of 2 "non ascii"s in your picture.

Comment: 2 **e2** added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm in a UTF8 shell:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
...
```

so first:

```
$ export LC_ALL=C
```

Then:

```
$ awk -F '' '                         # split record in fields
BEGIN { for(n=0;n<256;n++)            # iterate all values
            ord[sprintf("%c",n)]=n }  # make a hash ord[char]=n
      { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)            # iterate all fields
            if(ord[$i]>127)           # beyond 7f
                print ord[$i] }       # print n (value)
' test
```

Outputs:

```
226
128
156
226
128
157
226
128
156
226
128
157
```

which in hex would be:

```
e2
80
9c
...
```

Comment: Maybe explain a little more in detail how the basic problem is that you need to pass the character's numeric ASCII code, not the character itself, to the print function, and that Awk has no built-in `ord()` function so you worked around that by creating an array.

Comment: @AlecJacobson Which awk are you on?