# How to list all of the unique non-ascii characters in a file?

Tags: bash, sed, unicode, ascii

Consider this [README.md](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alecjacobson/computer-graphics-kinematics/master/README.md), which contains many non-ascii, unicode characters.

I'd like to extract all of the unique non-ascii characters using bash (on OSX preferably).

For example, I'd like as output:

```
²
³
½
×
–
‖
→
↔
∀
∂
∆
∈
≈
≥
️
```

Currently, I have a rather cumbersome command and I wonder if it can be improved:

```
LC_ALL=C  cat README.md | sed -n "s/\(.\)/\1 /pg" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep  '[^ -~]' | sort | uniq
```

[related question, but awk-based answers are printed as byte-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43337015/how-to-list-all-non-ascii-bytes-with-awk)

Comment: I would use perl for that: `perl -CiIO -nle '$h{$_}++ for /\P{ASCII}/g;END{print for keys %h}' /path/to/README.md`. That could be easily changed to sort them or show how many of each there are.

Answer (score 2):

`sed 's/[\x00-\x7F]//g'` is the simplest way I can think of filtering out ASCII characters. You can combine that with `grep -o .` to get one character per line. And `sort -u` is equivalent to `sort | uniq`. All this gives:

```
$ echo 2²3³ | sed 's/[\x00-\x7F]//g' | grep -o . | sort -u

²
³
```

Answer (score 1):

A variant using grep:

```
grep -ohP '[^\x00-\x7F]' README.md | sort -u
```

Comment: On OSX, BSD grep doesn't support this but installing GNU grep (via `brew install grep` and then `ggrep` does).

Answer (score 1):

And using Python, from the shell:

```
python3 -c "print('\n'.join(sorted(char for char in open('README.md').read() if ord(char) > 127)))"
```

For no repeats:

```
python3 -c "print('\n'.join(sorted({char for char in open('README.md').read() if ord(char) > 127})))"
```

Comment: I guess there's probably a slick python `unique` that I could use here to get no repeats?

Comment: Yes - I added that to the answer - just enclosing the innermost generator expression in `{ }` make a "set comprehension" out of it, and the net effect is that just one character of it is held (and then fed into the "sorted" call)